# Как настроить клавиатуру на отображение определенных символов в Android?

Tags: android, клавиатура

Я хочу, чтобы знак ',' был не просто неактивным, а вообще отсутствовал на клавиатуре. Как это можно сделать?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MyEd"
    android:layout_x="53dp"
    android:layout_y="80dp"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:focusable="true"  
    android:textColor="@drawable/ed_text_selector"
    android:background="@drawable/ed_text_rounded"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:maxLength="25"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>
```

Comment: Никак не сделаешь

Comment: Вызывайте свою программную клавиатуру в которой будут только нужные кнопки.